Reading from MAT files(or similarly from other options) to CUDA/C
For a project I need sparse matrices retrieved from this website: https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/list_by_id.html
Where matrices are in the form of .MAT and other formats which I am not very familiar with. I need to get these matrices into cuda/c code to multiply these matrices. I could not do the getting data from the file, any help or idea is appreciated.
I looked from many sites say, using <mat.h> or converting .mat file to a textfile using matlab. In these trials, sparsity is lost all I left with is non-zero matrix data. I would love to find out if there is a possible way.

The second format (MM) is Matrix Market I think. It might be much better suited for CUDA/C, at least that is the one I'm using. The Ginkgo project is able to read and multiply matrices from these files on GPUs from most vendors but it is a C++ library.

the .rb files should be Rutherford Boeing format. This library looks like it can read them. In particular, the spral_rb_read function looks like it should store the results in CSC, which is compatible with Cuda's sparse CSC format.

I don’t understand this question — NIST have provided standard libraries for reading all the conventional sparse matrix interchange formats for about the last 20 years or so.  Can’t you use one of those? https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html

With scipy.io.loadmat I can load one of the .mat files from your directory.
loadmat can load *.mat files ('old style').  If there were sparse in MATLAB, it can also create a scipy.sparse matrix from that data.  To do this is has to load 3 data arrays which store that underlying sparse coordinates and data, and then run sparse.csc_matrix(...).
To do the same in some other packages, it would need to both be able load the .mat, and create a sparse matrix
In [23]: from scipy.io import loadmat
In [24]: data = loadmat('Downloads/494_bus.mat')

In [25]: data
Out[25]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on: Sat Sep  6 04:04:21 2008',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'Problem': array([[(array(['S ADMITTANCE MATRIX  494 BUS POWER SYSTEM, D.J.TYLAVSKY, JULY 1985.'],
               dtype='<U67'), <494x494 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
            with 1666 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>, array(['HB/494_bus'], dtype='<U10'), array([[2]], dtype=uint8), array(['1985'], dtype='<U4'), array(['D. Tylavsky'], dtype='<U11'), array(['I. Duff, R. Grimes, J. Lewis'], dtype='<U28'), array(['power network problem'], dtype='<U21'))]],
       dtype=[('title', 'O'), ('A', 'O'), ('name', 'O'), ('id', 'O'), ('date', 'O'), ('author', 'O'), ('ed', 'O'), ('kind', 'O')])}

Specify the variable 'Problem', the structured array field 'A', and the element of that (1,1) shaped array.
In [26]: data['Problem']['A'].item()
Out[26]: 
<494x494 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1666 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [27]: data['Problem']['A'].item().A
Out[27]: 
array([[2220.874  ,    0.     ,    0.     , ...,    0.     ,    0.     ,
           0.     ],
       [   0.     ,    5.41067,    0.     , ...,    0.     ,    0.     ,
           0.     ],
       [   0.     ,    0.     ,   13.57086, ...,    0.     ,    0.     ,
           0.     ],
       ...,
       [   0.     ,    0.     ,    0.     , ...,   54.05405,    0.     ,
           0.     ],
       [   0.     ,    0.     ,    0.     , ...,    0.     ,  111.6384 ,
           0.     ],
       [   0.     ,    0.     ,    0.     , ...,    0.     ,    0.     ,
         110.9479 ]])


OP is asking for a C solution...

I think I could use this to generate text format then import to C. What do you think? would it work ?

I'm haven't used other sparse formats such as MM. If you convert a sparse CSC to COO, you could easily write the 3 equal size arrays to a CSV style text file.  With CSC format, the indptr array is different size. It should help if you understand sparse arrays at the destination language end.
